# How to use Google Script to email a pdf of just one sheet (tab) within a spreadsheet/

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have located some similar posts but none of the solutions seemed to work.

I have a function that sends me an email PDF of a spreadsheet. I just want the email attachment to send the first sheet (tab) in the spreadsheet which is just titled "Report" I don't want it to send the other tabs. Can someone help me modify the script below to just send the first tab?

The script I have so far is:

```
function publish() 

{ var message = { to: "Redacted email address", 

subject: "Report",

    body: "Attached is the report",

    name: "Report",

    attachments: [SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getAs(MimeType.PDF).setName("Report")]
  }
  MailApp.sendEmail(message);
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the active sheet as PDF like this:

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
const url = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${ ss.getId() }/export?exportFormat=pdf&gid=${ sheet.getId() }&access_token=${ ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() }`;
const blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob().setName(`Report - ${ sheet.getName() }`;
```

Then set `attachments: [blob]`.